# Wordpress database query not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

apologies that this is very basic stuff but would really appreciate some help. I am trying to query a table in my Wordpress database by adding the following to my child theme's functions.php

```
$myresults = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM wp_my_table WHERE user_id=1");
```

I am trying to view the results of the query by adding

```
<?php
    var_dump($myresults);
?>
```

to one of the pages on my website, but it just displays 'NULL'. I have checked using phpMyAdmin and wp_my_table definitely exists, and contains entries where user_id=1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

not get_results!!!  query

```
$wpdb->get_results(...
```

to

```
$wpdb->query(...
```

Comment: Not working unfortunately - the var_dump still displays 'NULL'

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what that means!

Comment: Send the part of the code where you connect to the database

Comment: I thought I didn't have to open a separate DB connection with $wpdb? The rest of the website works great so the database connection must be fine I guess? I have tried adding global $wpdb; before my code but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I missed something obvious - the scope of the $myresults variable didn't extend to the page I was performing the var_dump on!